# Sizing a Cuckoo filter for a subset of elements

Tags: data-structures, probabilistic-algorithms

### Question

I am considering the use of Cuckoo filter for a business case. To simplify the explanation here is an analogy of my needs:

1. There are over $n = 30 000$ first names that exists in the whole world
2. I have a Cuckoo filter storing the names of people who gave me a gift at least once
3. I am certain that the Cuckoo filter will not have to store more than **600** names
4. The names the Cuckoo filter will store are evenly distributed across the 30 000 names
5. Of course the final goal is to be able to know which names gave me a gift at least once, **I might have to query for any of the 30 000 names**.

I would like to design my filter for 600 elements; however the original paper about Cuckoo filters considers that the number of buckets $m$ is a multiple of $n$.

> Now consider a construction process that inserts $n$ random items to an empty table of $m=cn$ buckets for a constant $c$

Am I supposed to size the filter according to set of all names in the world ? Is there something I am missing ? This is not addressed in the original publication.

### Constraints

**Size** : The Cuckoo filter will be transmitted over the network. But it will be done in an asynchronous way (let's say an update every 2 hours). So this will weigh in the size constraint.

**Time** : The real constraint is time. When I query the filter I would like my response in less than 5 seconds.

**False positive** : I also hope to have false positive rate of at most 20%.

**Security** : In my example I store names, but in reality I will store sensitive data that should be protected and anonymized under GDPR. After a statistical analysis I concluded that the data's entropy is too low to store as a list of hashes.

**Other options** : I'm open minded by nature. I always welcome other options.

### Attempt at a self answer

Considering that the fingerprint is $f$ bits long, and I have $m$ buckets, the probability that the name Bob has the same features (index and fingerprint) as the name Alice is :

$$
\frac{1}{2^f} \cdot \frac{1}{m}
$$

Which means that the probability that there is another name colliding with the name  Anna is:

$$
(n - 1) \cdot \frac{1}{2^f} \cdot \frac{1}{m}
$$

With 30 000 names, a fingerprint of 8 bits and 600 buckets, the result is $0.39$ which means a false positive rate of **39 %**.

To reduce the false positive rate I can either increase the fingerprint size or the number of buckets. Using 6000 buckets instead of 600 gives me a false positive rate of **3.9%**. This hack might be working in my example case but in reality we are talking of $10^{19}$ names in the whole world and $10000$ names to store in the filter.

It seems to me that Cuckoo filter were not designed with this use case in mind, and when people are using Cuckoo filter, they hope to store almost every existing item in there at some point.

Comment: The number of possible names shouldn't factor in. It could be infinite. The relevant number is 600.

Comment: If `Anna` and `Bob` collide (same fingerprint and index). I add `Anna` to the filter. I query the filter for `Bob`. I get a false positive. I guess I don't see how I cannot factor the number of possible names in this.

Comment: You might be right. In that case, it is certainly true that you are "supposed to size the filter according to set of all names in the world", so I'm not quite sure what your question is.

Comment: It might help to give a pointer to Cuckoo filters, and explain how exactly you are planning to use them, and what guarantees you are after.

Comment: The use case is exactly what I described in the question, I am looking to get the best false positive rate possible, at least 90%.

Comment: I am not a math or data structures expert so I was looking for an external opinion on this issue, which you gave me. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Check [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06067.pdf). There is a formula for the false positive rate at the first line of the second page. This formula only refers to fingerprints – you also need to factor it fingerprint collision.

Comment: By the way, assuming 300,000 names, it takes about 6240 bits to store the list of all names, though updating and querying the list might be a bit slow. If space is at premium but time is not, that's also an option. The calculation is roughly to take the base-2 logarithm of $\binom{300,000}{\leq 600}$.

Comment: Thanks that's a great resource. I think I also saw this formula in the original paper.

Comment: Okay I get what you said when you asked for more clarification about the use case now. Space is not really a big constraint, but the cuckoo filters will be transmitted over the network. Time will be the real constraint, the query needs to be done as soon as possible as it might be used in real time operations.

Comment: I get why the updating might be slow because of the relocations. But I think the querying won't, am I wrong ? I just need to compute the index and fingerprint and check the table.

Comment: I was suggesting a different method with no errors. It will be quite slow. You can use hashing to speed it up at the cost of increasing the size and having a small probability of failure, but still no errors (unless there is failure).

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion. Would you mind giving me some references to study so I can get a better understanding ?

Comment: My suggestion is to use something similar to the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), though you don't have a fixed $k$ in mind (but that's not a huge difference). There might be some trick to make insertions and queries efficient, but if you don't find any, you can use hashing to reduce the parameters to manageable sizes which will enable reasonably fast insertion and query.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing your question to make sure all relevant information is in the question.  I don't see the target false positive rate mentioned in the question.  Are you dead-set on using cuckoo filters, or would you be open to some other solution?  For example, why not store store a list of the 600 names and do lookups with binary search?  That will be fast and have no false positives.

Comment: Thanks for the help @D.W. I updated my question to add all the relevant information.

Comment: "false positive rate of at least 80%" - is that really right?  Normally a lower false positive rate is better.  did you mean "at most 2%" or something like that?

Comment: The 300 000 is a typo, I corrected it. There was a confusion about the false positive rate. I keep using it wrong, it was obviously "at most 20%". As many people here English is not my first language, and writing math in English is especially challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments it turns out that, yes, I need to size my Cuckoo filter for the set of every existing name. That being said, it is not much of a problem in the end if I only send the buckets with fingerprints in it, which shouldn't be more than 600.

In addition to that, my attempt at a self answer was very wrong. The probability that there is another name colliding with the name Anna is actually:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) =  \sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \sum_{1 \le i \lt j ... \lt k \le n} P(A_i \cap A_j ... \cap A_k)$$

This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Because of my hypotheses, the probability can be simplified as:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) =  1 - (1 - p)^n$$

As highlighted in the original paper, we also have to take into account that $$2b/2^f \le \epsilon$$.